# Can gettext handle messages with multiple plural variables

Tags: internationalization, gettext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internationalising sentences with two plural words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888487/internationalising-sentences-with-two-plural-words)

How would a message with two plural variables be handled in gettext - for example:

```
#, python-format 
msgid "Answered a question more than %(days)d days later with at least %(votes)d votes" 
msgstr ""
```

Of course this is not in plural form. We want to turn it into plural form where the correct form of the message can be retrieved based on the values of both variables.

I am aware of course that the message can be split into parts, each part translated separately then assembled in code, but that goes against i18n best practices as the way the parts are aggregated might not be suitable for the language we are translating to.

Comment: It can't you need to simplify your english http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888487/internationalising-sentences-with-two-plural-words