# How can I convert a Zend localization/translation array to gettext?

Tags: zend-framework, localization, translation, gettext, zend-translate

My multi-lingual site already successfully uses the "array" method of Zend translations.

I want to convert from that method to the "gettext" method because I've read that gettext is superior.

I've tried using http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/php2po.html but can't get it to work.

I think it's not meant to handle Zend arrays as the input.

My Zend file (which works) looks like this:

```
<?php

return array(    
    'choose your favorite stores' => 'Choose your %1$sfavorite stores%2$s',
    'P.S. If you ever have question' => 'P.S. If you ever have questions, %1$semail us%2$s any time.',
    'You can also find quick answer' => 'You can also find quick answers on our %1$sHelp page%2$s.',
    'Earn X cash' => '%1$sEarn 1-30%% cash back%2$s, get money-saving coupons, and find the best price on every purchase at %3$s2,500+ stores%4$s.'
);
```

(But it's much longer, and I have multiple languages, each in their own PHP file.)

Comment: And I'm worried about the ordered variables, too, especially after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888487.  Because I need to be able to do the following. Notice how the order of the variables is different in English and Chinese: 
 `'Earn X cash' => '%1$sEarn 1-30%% cash back%2$s, get money-saving coupons, and find the best price on every purchase at %3$s2,500+ stores%4$s.'`
and
 `'Earn X cash' => '您可从%3$s2500个商家%4$s中，找到省钱的优惠券，轻松比价，更可获取%1$s1-30%%的返利%2$s。'`

Answer (score 0):

With the snippet you have given the conversion works for me.

```
$ php2po en.php en.po -t en.php 
processing 1 files...
[###########################################] 100%

$ cat en.po 
#. extracted from en.php, en.php
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-12-19 10:08+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Translate Toolkit 1.9.1-pre\n"

#: return+array%28-%3E%27choose+your+favorite+stores%27
msgid "Choose your %1$sfavorite stores%2$s"
msgstr "Choose your %1$sfavorite stores%2$s"

#: return+array%28-%3E%27P.S.+If+you+ever+have+question%27
msgid "P.S. If you ever have questions, %1$semail us%2$s any time."
msgstr "P.S. If you ever have questions, %1$semail us%2$s any time."

#: return+array%28-%3E%27You+can+also+find+quick+answer%27
msgid "You can also find quick answers on our %1$sHelp page%2$s."
msgstr "You can also find quick answers on our %1$sHelp page%2$s."
```

I'm using a Translate Toolkit version from [git master](https://github.com/translate/translate), maybe you should try that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that, but unfortunately it skips the 4th key/value pair in the array ('Earn X cash').

Comment: Also, it fails to use the array key as the msgid.

Comment: If you add a comma in the last element of the array that will be included too. The key of the array won't be used as a `msgid`, why would you want that? You are converting from a monolingual format to a bilingual format. PO files will always have the source text (English in this case) in the `msgid`; that's what you expect localizers to localize.

Comment: There are many cases where you'd want the "key" (msgid) to be different from the source text (English).  For example, in the HTML view, I might want to say <a href="[xxxx]">[yyyy]</a> where the destination and label of that anchor tag depend on the locale of the user.  E.g. it might be a link to a social network, and in US it would be Facebook but in China it would be Weibo.  So the MsgIds might be something like socialSiteUrl and socialSiteLabel.  I am trying to get poeditor.com to work. That might be my approach going forward.

Comment: I ignore if the Zend framework forces you a specific format... but what I don't understand is the reason why you want to convert this to PO if you are not going to use the result as a bilingual format.