# php ngettext multiple variables

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

Copying the example from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php), ngettext works like this:

```
ngettext("%d window", "%d windows", 1); //'1 window';
ngettext("%d window", "%d windows", 2); //'2 windows';
```

But what if I want to use 2 variables, for example `%d windows %d doors`? Is there a standard way to implement this, so that the correct string (4 combinations) appears based on the 2 variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngettext()` does not support multiple variables. You have to make sure to write sentences that can be properly translated block by block (if possible multiple sentences to avoid issues with language-dependent ordering).

At least one reason why this is not supported is that the number of requisite fallback sentences (first parameters of `ngettext()`) would grow exponentially with the number of variables (i.e. you would need 4 such sentences for 2 variables: singular-singular, singular-plural, plural-singular and plural-plural, then 8 for 3 variables, etc.).

You will find an answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1893929/4457767.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**
     * Function that will return the correct word related to quantity.
     * @param type Int $quantity
     * @param type String $singular
     * @param type String $plural
     * @param type Boolean $showQuantity
     * @return type String
     */
    function pluralize( $quantity, $singular, $plural, $showQuantity=true ) {
        return ( $showQuantity ? $quantity." " : "" ) . ( $quantity > 1 ? $plural : $singular );
    }
```